# Converting 3D matrix to cascaded 2D Matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, reshape

I have a `3D` matrix in python as the following:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((2,2,3))
a[0,0,0] = 2
a[0,0,1] = 3
a[0,0,2] = 4
```

I want to convert this `3D` matrix to a set of `2D` matrices. I have tried `np.reshape` but it did not solve my problem. The final shape I am interested in is the following cascaded vesrsion:

```
 [[ 2.  1.  3.  1.  4.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

However, `np.reshape` gives me the following

```
 [[ 2.  3.  4.  1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) alongwith [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) -

```
a.transpose([0,2,1]).reshape(a.shape[0],-1)
```

Or use [`swapaxes`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) that does the same job as `transpose` alongwith `reshape` -

```
a.swapaxes(2,1).reshape(a.shape[0],-1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [66]: a
Out[66]: 
array([[[ 2.,  3.,  4.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]])

In [67]: a.transpose([0,2,1]).reshape(a.shape[0],-1)
Out[67]: 
array([[ 2.,  1.,  3.,  1.,  4.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])

In [68]: a.swapaxes(2,1).reshape(a.shape[0],-1)
Out[68]: 
array([[ 2.,  1.,  3.,  1.,  4.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```